# java get next few words in string

Tags: java, html, string, search, split

I am trying to search a .txt file that contains HTML in it. I need to search the file for specific HTML tags, then grab the following next few characters of code. I am new to java, but am willing to learn what I need to.

For example: Say I have the code: `<span class="date">Apr 13</span>` and all I need is the date(Apr 13). How do I go about doing this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `grab the following next few characters of code`..What is the definition of **FEW** ?

Comment: You will need to provide more information than this. Samples from the file you are searching in, patterns you are looking for and most importantly, *what have you tried* will help us better answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [String class docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and try to find the method to search the string.

- Since you said you are getting it from a HTML file, you can have a look at [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) which is a HTML parser, which will make searching for strings in HTML documents a lot easier.

With jsoup, you can do it like this

```
File input = new File("input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

Elements spans = doc.select("span"); 
for (Element element : spans) {
    System.out.println(element.html());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(">(.*?)<").matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) {
        String s = m.group(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want is something **basic** (I thought it would be good as you are new), you can use this :

```
if(s.indexOf("span class=\"date\"")!=0)
s=s.substring(s.indexOf(">")+1,s.lastIndexOf("<"));
```

But this answer is **specific** to your question than a broad one

Answer (score 0):

```
String yourString = "<span class=\"date\">Apr 13</span>"
String date = yourString.split("class=\"date\">")[1].split("</sp")[0];
```

Comment: This works for the string of the question. But parsing XML is difficult.

Comment: Yes it is difficult to parse a XML file but in my opinion if you know what are the names of the classes you want you can get them all using the same method. This is a good method if you have 1 to 10 different classes. If you have a random number of classes you better use another method then.